# WPF Custom button with image and text not clickable on textblock

Tags: wpf

I have a custom button which includes a ticker symbol and an image. Everything works exactly as I need except onMouseover when I want to click the button. The entire button (cursor hand) shows if I mouseover any part of the button (including the image) that DOES NOT contain the textbox. Therefore clicking on the stock symbol (crosshair shows not hand cursor) does not execute my command. I am missing something stupid and I just cant put my finger on it.  ANY help would be greatly appreciated. This is from my resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="TickerButtonStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <Button.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SwitchViewCommand, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,      
                                        AncestorType={x:Type local:MainView}}}" />
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Ticker}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Border Name="bd" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                                              BorderThickness="0"
                                                              Margin="0"
                                                              Background="Transparent">
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent">
                                                    <TextBox Name="txt" IsReadOnly="True" 
                                                         BorderThickness="0"
                                                         BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                                         Background="Transparent"
                                                         TextAlignment="Left"
                                                         Foreground="White"
                                                         FontFamily="Ariel" 
                                                         FontSize="12"
                                                         Text="{Binding Path=Ticker, Converter={StaticResource tickerSymbolDisplay}}"
                                                         />
                                                    <Image Width="16" Height="11" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=Ticker, Converter={StaticResource tickerImageDisplay}}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Border>
                                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                    <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Foreground" Value="#FF7E00"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="View Fundamentals"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Resources>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: OMG, I knew it was something dumb I was doing. That fixed it. Thanks!!!

Comment: if your asking a question don't post all your XAML 
just the parts relevant to the reader . 
no body cares about your Alignment's and Colors and  stuff , 
and notice that you wrote TextBlock instead of TextBox in the Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a TextBlock instead of a TextBox:

```
<TextBlock Name="txt"
Background="Transparent" 
TextAlignment="Left"
Foreground="White"
FontFamily="Ariel" 
FontSize="12"
Text="ticker"
Text="{Binding Path=Ticker, Converter={StaticResource tickerSymbolDisplay}}"
/>
```